# Is there a way to have neo4j / cypher place constraint on a nested property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to put a uniqueness constraint on value.path, how can I do it ?

```
{
  "identity": 16866,
  "labels": [
    "Component"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "asset_id": "",
    "id": "ComponentIdentity",
    "version": "#head",
    "value": "{
            "id": "f75cb59f-85ce-4247-979a-c8c8784b98d4",
            "path": "interactions.json"
        }"
  },
  "elementId": "16866"
}
```

I have tried

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ComponentPathUniqueness IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Component)
REQUIRE n.value.path IS NODE UNIQUE
```

But it fails with Invalid input '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persisting nested properties [is not supported by Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/appendix/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-properties) so what you describe is not feasible.

Instead of nesting properties, you can define an extra node and link it to the original node with a relationship.
Alternatively, you can "flatten" the nested properties to a non-nested dictionary of properties.